# Vertical scrolling in scrollview

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, three20

I am using Three20's TTscrollview for pdf display. It's work fine for horizontal swipe.Now I need vertical scrolling not horizontal. So how to do that anybody know about do this vertical scrolling with TTScrollview.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you set the contentSize of the scrollView. If the contentSize is set for one direction larger than the scrollView's frame then you should be able to scroll to that direction. So, play with the contentSize and see if it works.